# LINQ GroupBy generated incomplete query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have an extremely simple use-case for LINQ and I'm stuck with it for hours now. The following code returns a list (1 group element without name) in a list. Why isn't it translated correctly in SQL? I use EF Core 2.2.

My TileDetail Model Class:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;
using System;

namespace FAST_API.Models
{
    public class TileDetailsContext : DbContext
    {
        public TileDetailsContext(DbContextOptions<TileDetailsContext> options)
          : base(options)
        {
        }
        public DbQuery<TileDetail> TileDetailsItems{ get;set; }
    }
    [Table("WFD_MOTOR_EVENTS_AUFTRAEGE", Schema = "SF")]
    public class TileDetail
    {
        public string AUFTRAG { get; set; }
        public string PMPS { get; set; }
        public string ESN { get; set; }
        public string AUFTRAGSBEZ { get; set; }
        public int VORGANGSNR { get; set; }
        public string VORGANGSTEXT { get; set; }

        public char AUFTRAG_FERTIG { get; set;}
        public double? IST_BEGINN { get; set; }
        public double? IST_ENDE { get; set; }
        public DateTime? AG_IST_BEGINN {
            get { return (IST_BEGINN == null ? (DateTime?)null: new DateTime(1970,1,1).AddDays(Convert.ToDouble(IST_BEGINN))); }
        }
        public DateTime? AG_IST_ENDE {
            get { return (IST_ENDE == null ? (DateTime?)null: new DateTime(1970,1,1).AddDays(Convert.ToDouble(IST_ENDE))); }
        }

        public char VORGANG_FERTIG { get; set; }
        public bool AUFTRAG_FERTIG_STATUS {
            get { return AUFTRAG_FERTIG != 'J' ? true: false; }
        }
        public bool VORGANG_FERTIG_STATUS {
            get { return VORGANG_FERTIG != 'J' ? true: false; }
        }
    }
}
```

**This is my controller where I use LINQ**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using FAST_API.Models;

namespace FAST_API.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TileDetailsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly TileDetailsContext _context;

        public TileDetailsController(TileDetailsContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/TileDetails
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<TileDetail> GetTileDetailsItems()
        {
            return _context.TileDetailsItems.ToList();
        }

        // GET: api/TileDetails/706722
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetTileDetails([FromRoute] string id)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            var tileDetails = _context.TileDetailsItems.Where(x => x.ESN == id);

            if (tileDetails == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(tileDetails);
        }
        // GET: api/UniqueOrders/000096543182
        [HttpGet("UniqueOrders/{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetUniqueOrders([FromRoute] string id)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            var tileDetails = _context.TileDetailsItems
            .Select(m => new {
                m.AUFTRAG, 
                m.AUFTRAGSBEZ, 
                m.PMPS,
                m.AUFTRAG_FERTIG_STATUS,
                m.ESN
            })
            .Where(x => x.ESN == id)
            .GroupBy(m => new {
                m.AUFTRAG, 
                m.AUFTRAGSBEZ, 
                m.PMPS,
                m.AUFTRAG_FERTIG_STATUS,
                m.ESN
            });

            if (tileDetails == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(tileDetails);
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? My expectation is a query like this:

```
SELECT "m"."AUFTRAG", "m"."AUFTRAGSBEZ", "m"."PMPS", "m"."AUFTRAG_FERTIG", "m"."ESN"
FROM "SF"."WFD_MOTOR_EVENTS_AUFTRAEGE" "m"
GROUP BY "m"."AUFTRAG", "m"."AUFTRAGSBEZ", "m"."PMPS", "m"."AUFTRAG_FERTIG", "m"."ESN"
HAVING "m"."ESN" = '567274'
```

Instead this is generated (Where is the "GROUP BY" clause???):

```
SELECT "m"."AUFTRAG", "m"."AUFTRAGSBEZ", "m"."PMPS", "m"."AUFTRAG_FERTIG", "m"."ESN"
FROM "SF"."WFD_MOTOR_EVENTS_AUFTRAEGE" "m"
WHERE "m"."ESN" = :id_0
ORDER BY "m"."AUFTRAG" NULLS FIRST, "m"."AUFTRAGSBEZ" NULLS FIRST, "m"."PMPS" NULLS FIRST, "m"."AUFTRAG_FERTIG" NULLS FIRST, "m"."ESN" NULLS FIRST
```

Comment: Try adding `.ToList()` at the end.

Comment: you have a where before the group by -- you want a having -- having happens after the group by.

Answer (score 0):

Your both sql query is equivalent in your case. 
At "select" part you have same fields as at "group" part and don't have any aggregate function. Also there is no aggregation function in `having`. So `having` work in you case as filter like `where`.

Expression `GROUP BY "m"."AUFTRAG", "m"."AUFTRAGSBEZ", "m"."PMPS", "m"."AUFTRAG_FERTIG", "m"."ESN"` mean that you group by first field, then by second and etc. and also order result by first field, then by second and etc. Because you don't have any aggregation function at "select" part and fields at select part is same as at "group by" part them compiler change group by into order by.

But in my opinion compiler should add `Distinct` into "select" part in you case.

So you should simplify your code to:

```
var tileDetails = _context.TileDetailsItems
            .Where(x => x.ESN == id)
            .Select(m => new {
                m.AUFTRAG, 
                m.AUFTRAGSBEZ, 
                m.PMPS,
                m.AUFTRAG_FERTIG_STATUS,
                m.ESN
            }).Distinct();
```